# Delete MySQL8 SELECT ... INTO FILE files without root rights nor mysql user

Tags: mysql

Since MySQL8, we aren't able to delete  files generated with SELECT ... INTO FILE with a non-root/mysql user.

This is related to the note here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

We want to generate those files via PHP, use them, then delete them. For disk capacity reasons we have to delete them inside our process. For obvious security reasons, we won't give PHP root rights nor run PHP with MYSQL user.

How can we manage to make PHP delete those files?

Comment: You could give the PHP user write access to the folder in which the files are created, that would allow that user to delete files generated in that folder by MySQL user.

Answer (score 0):

@Matteo Tassinari answered my question. Rights access to the folder solved my problem. Thanks!